# Changing alt gr key to different key to type special caracters

Tags: special-characters

I need to type Latvian and therefore need to use special characters as `ļ`, `ņ`, `š` and so on. Pressing and holding <kbd>alt gr</kbd> while typing is real problematic.

Is there a way to assign different key and set it so I need to  press it once?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Latvian language pack:

Go to `System Settings -> Language Support` and click on the <kbd>Install / Remove Languages...</kbd> button.

From here install the "Latvian" language and it will now appear in your language dropdown menu on the right side of your top bar.

Or you can just add Latvian as a text entry method from `System Settings -> Text Entry`.

[image: Text Entry]

Use the <kbd>+</kbd> button on the lower left to add Latvian as a text entry option and then you can configure your keyboard shortcut to switch between input types (or just stick with the default of <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>).